# Is there a good way to send an eCheck from outside the US?

Tags: international-transfer, payment

Does anyone know a service that would allow an Australian resident to draft an eCheck payable to a US recipient?

I'm an Australian writer doing some historical research. I'm trying to request some documents from the Colorado State Archives. The options available to pay for a document request are credit/debit card, mailing a cheque/money order, or an "Electronic Check" (eCheck). I've tried paying via my Visa debit card, a Mastercard, and my Wise account, however all these cards are declined. I assume the card payment is restricted to BIN ranges corresponding to US banks. My Australian bank won't draft international money orders anymore, so it would seem that the only option remaining is eCheck. I understand PayPal used to provide this service, but I can't seem to access it via my account. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Please forgive me if this question is not a good fit for this StackExchange.

Comment: E-check is essentially an electronic copy of a check. You'll need a Federal Reserve System routing number for your bank and an account number. I.e.: you need an account in a US bank.